# Calculating the average time between button clicks

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, for-loop

I'm doing this Windows Forms application in C# so when you click this button multiple times, it calculates the average clicks per second you do.

I just yesterday started learning C# and the only language im good at is Lua. In Lua this would be simple, just use a table as they're very dynamic and flexible. I just have no clue how to do this in C#, the MSDN Articles just confuse me.

How would I store the times between clicks? Arrays? I have no clue. This is the button click function I have so far

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //DO STUFF

}
```

Comment: Use a `List<int>`, you can then use Linq to calculate the average.

Comment: Show some effort, people wont do your homework so easily.

Comment: `//DO STUFF` isn't having "anything so far"

Comment: solid attempt thus far

Comment: How do I use List? The MSDN articles always confuse me D:

Comment: can you elaborate you question?

Comment: "The MSDN articles always confuse me" - you're going to have to give us more than that. What's confusing about it? Define a list (same as creating a Lua table), add stuff to it (similar to adding a new entry to a Lua table), iterate it with a for loop to get the average (same as Lua). Give it a shot and tell us what you're missing. Not that you're confused.

Comment: Google some examples or read a book. SO will not teach you how to use a List.

Comment: I would recommend editing your title to be more specific (and remove the C# "tag" from the title), and saying what you've tried so far.  You'll likely get the question reopened (though my answer should work for you anyways).

Answer (score 6):

You could store the time of each click, then compute the average of the times between them:

```
private List<DateTime> clickTimes = new List<DateTime>();
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.clickTimes.Add(DateTime.Now);

    if (this.clickTimes.Count > 2)
    {
         double averageSeconds = this.clickTimes.Zip(this.clickTimes.Skip(1), (a,b) => (b-a).TotalSeconds)).Average();

         // Do something with the average seconds between each click here
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting - why all of the downvotes?

Comment: Downvote not for correctness, but for complexity. Doubt OP will get this within the next 6 months.

Comment: @CSharpie Frankly, that's ridiculous.  Showing a correct, succinct answer provides the OP a way to learn how to approach the problem in a nice manner.

Comment: Since when do we downvote correct answers because the OP asks a bad question and isn't likely to put in the effort to understand it???

Comment: I hate downvotes without reasons, that privelege should require higher reputation